# How to call controller's(method) from kernal.php in (scheduler) laravel5

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5, scheduler

## controller file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Repositories\CampaignpostRepository;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Exception\Handler;
use DB;
class CampaignpostController extends Controller {

    protected $campaign_gestion;
    /**
     * Store a new user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */

    public function __construct(
    CampaignpostRepository $campaign_gestion)
   {
       $this->campaign_gestion = $campaign_gestion;
   }

     public function index()
    {
    }
```

## kernal.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
 {
//  $schedule->command('inspire')
//     ->hourly();
                $schedule->command('CampaignpostController@index')->everyMinute();
 }
```

i need to call CampaignpostController from kernal.php file
how can i call CampaignpostController.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
 {
   $schedule->call('CampaignpostController@index')->everyMinute();
 }
```